# Liberar Memoria en Raspberry usando chromium y nodejs

Tags: nodejs, angular

hago una aplicación web que corre en una Raspberry pi 3B+ con Rasbian lite sin desktop, todo lo hago por consola, uso xorg para servir chromim-browser, el cual hago un arranque automático desde xinitrc y rc.local. La aplicación tiene un backend con nodejs que continuamente por medio de setInterval consulta unos datos y por medio de socket.io lo envía al navegador, el frontend esta hecho con angular 7. No uso base de datos. en el frontend se muestran 4 gráficas (pastel, barra y 2 de linea) tiene otra pantalla que muestra una tabla con los datos (solo tiene esas dos pantallas). El problema es que el consumo de memoria aumenta rápidamente hasta superar el limite de 1GB que tiene la Raspberry y se Congela de modo que tengo que reiniciar.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que cada tiempo se libere memoria para evitar que se llegue al limite y se me congele?

Agradezco el que alguien me puede ayudar, dando algunas ideas, procedimiento o información para poder solucionar este problema.

Gracias

Comment: esta limpiando el set Interval al cerrar la app?

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que usar el "recolector de basura" (garbaje collector).

Dos formas:

1) Desde linea de comandos.
añadiendo `--max-old-space-size=128` a la linea que arranca nodejs.
Esto forzaría a ejecutar el recolector de basura interno cuando la memoria se acerque a los 128Mb (128Mb es lo que yo pongo en una Raspberry A+ con 512Mb)

2) Por programación.
Por ejemplo:

```
char * buffer;
buffer = (char*) malloc (42);

// Tareas a realizar con la variable.

// al terminar con la variable
//libero espacio que ocupa la variable en memoria
free (buffer);
```

X) Otra opción que se me ocurre que integres la aplicación en el framework electron ja. (el cual tiene chromiun-browser mas ligero y un nodejs)
al estar todo corriendo en la misma app deberías reducir el consumo de memoria.